# Datepicker no corre - Javascript - HTML - CSS

Tags: javascript, datepicker

Actualmente estoy trabajando con las librerías de datepicker pero no logro que al darle click el calendario se despliegue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.3/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.3/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/date.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-3'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</html>
</body>
```

El codigo js que estoy llamadndo desde la ruta "js/date.js"

Es el siguiente:

```html
 $(function () {
   var bindDatePicker = function() {
  $(".date").datetimepicker({
        format:'YYYY-MM-DD',
   icons: {
    time: "fa fa-clock-o",
    date: "fa fa-calendar",
    up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
    down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
   }
  }).find('input:first').on("blur",function () {
   // check if the date is correct. We can accept dd-mm-yyyy and yyyy-mm-dd.
   // update the format if it's yyyy-mm-dd
   var date = parseDate($(this).val());

   if (! isValidDate(date)) {
    //create date based on momentjs (we have that)
    date = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
   }

   $(this).val(date);
  });
 }
   
   var isValidDate = function(value, format) {
  format = format || false;
  // lets parse the date to the best of our knowledge
  if (format) {
   value = parseDate(value);
  }

  var timestamp = Date.parse(value);

  return isNaN(timestamp) == false;
   }
   
   var parseDate = function(value) {
  var m = value.match(/^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)?(\d{1,2})(\/|-)?(\d{4})$/);
  if (m)
   value = m[5] + '-' + ("00" + m[3]).slice(-2) + '-' + ("00" + m[1]).slice(-2);

  return value;
   }
   
   bindDatePicker();
 });
```

Debería funcionar de esta manera:
https://codepen.io/milz/pen/xbXpWw

Comment: habria que ver el arbol de directorios de tu proyecto

Comment: El arbol de directorios esta bien, el archivo local esta bien cargado, pero puedes ejecutar ese js directamente desde el html si asi lo deseas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function () {
   var bindDatePicker = function() {
  $(".date").datetimepicker({
        format:'YYYY-MM-DD',
   icons: {
    time: "fa fa-clock-o",
    date: "fa fa-calendar",
    up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
    down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
   }
  }).find('input:first').on("blur",function () {
   // check if the date is correct. We can accept dd-mm-yyyy and yyyy-mm-dd.
   // update the format if it's yyyy-mm-dd
   var date = parseDate($(this).val());

   if (! isValidDate(date)) {
    //create date based on momentjs (we have that)
    date = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
   }

   $(this).val(date);
  });
 }
   
   var isValidDate = function(value, format) {
  format = format || false;
  // lets parse the date to the best of our knowledge
  if (format) {
   value = parseDate(value);
  }

  var timestamp = Date.parse(value);

  return isNaN(timestamp) == false;
   }
   
   var parseDate = function(value) {
  var m = value.match(/^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)?(\d{1,2})(\/|-)?(\d{4})$/);
  if (m)
   value = m[5] + '-' + ("00" + m[3]).slice(-2) + '-' + ("00" + m[1]).slice(-2);

  return value;
   }
   
   bindDatePicker();
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.3/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.3/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-3'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</html>
</body>
```

Primero carga la libreria moment y luego bootstrap-datetimepicker, datetimepicker tiene dependencia de momento al parecer

Answer (score 0):

No te funciona porque estás llamando a datetimepicker sobre el selector `$(".date")` que es un div, intenta cambiar el selector a un input, puede ser trasladando la clase de CSS al input:

```
<div class='input-group' id='datetimepicker1'>
     <input type='text' class="form-control" />
     <span class="input-group-addon date">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"> 
         </span>
     </span>
</div>
```

Además, asegúrate de llamar la librería moment.js antes de llamar a datetimepicker en el head del html, en el codigo que pusiste la tienes después.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo básico de como utilizar el datepicker de JQuery.

```js
$(document).on("ready", function () {

    $(".monthpicker").datepicker({
        container: '#selectorId',
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        showButtonPanel: true
    });

});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="display: inline" aria-hidden="true"> 
  </span>
  </span>
  <input type="text" class="monthpicker form-control" autocomplete="off" style="background-color: gainsboro;" />
</div>
```